# If content field is empty display none

Tags: if-statement, content-management-system, twig

I'm trying to code a CMS with Bolt / Twig. Not very familiar with it, so need a little help.

On one page there's supposed to be an image that has a link in it. But if contentlink or image is empty it should be display none. 
So i wrote:

```
{% if record.contentlink %} 
  <a href="{{ record.contentlink }}">
     {% if record.image!="" %}
        <img src="{{ image(record.image, 672, 448) }}">
  {% endif %}</a>
{% endif %}

{% if contentlink is empty %}
   <a class="none"></a>
{% endif %}
```

The CSS is just:

```
.none {
display: none;
}
```

Problem is that if contentlink is empty a small box shows up where the link would have been:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jKGI.png)

Any tips?

Comment: This could be a css precedence issue. Be sure no other css rules are interfering with the `display:none` rule. Also, why don't you just output nothing when the mage and/or link is empty? Adding an element you then hide seems bit weird.

Comment: Hi! I think I found a better way to do it actually. Just used a {% if record.contentlink is not empty %}  and then made a partial to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a better way to do it actually. Just used:

```
{% if record.contentlink is not empty %}
```

and then made a partial to include.